# Python: Select specific parent object automatically on selection change?

Tags: python, selection-tools

I have written an add-on which visualizes objects on a racing game track.

Each in-game object is an empty object in Blender with one or more children mesh objects being the visible model as seen in-game. The empty holds the game-relevant properties in a `PropertyGroup` which are visualized in a custom `Panel`.

Basically, the object hierarchy looks like this:

- **ItemBox** < Empty object holding custom properties the user is interested in

  - ItemBoxOuter < A model the user selects
  - ItemBoxQuestionMark < Just another model the user might also select
- **Start** < Another empty holding custom properties

  - StartLine < Another model
- *and so on*

Since empties are hard to select and often covered and encased by the models, I want to redirect the selection of such child mesh objects to the parent empty object. Is it possible to modify how the selection operator works here?

Background: At first I worked around this by letting the `Panel` which displays the `PropertyGroup` use the parent object to show its data. However, users began to move around the child model objects (having selected those), effectively keeping the in-game object at the same place as it uses the transform of the empty object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve this with an apphandler I registered to. I added a custom property to the model objects to recognize them in there.

```
def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post.append(addon.scene_update_post)

def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post.remove(addon.scene_update_post)

# ---- In the addon module ----

def scene_update_post(scene):
    ob = scene.objects.active
    if ob:
        # Redirect the selection of a model mesh object to the parent track object.
        if ob.is_model:
            scene.objects.active = ob.parent
            ob.parent.select = True
            ob.select = False
```

This works even when multi selecting objects!